# Why is my predictor variable being split up in a logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic

I am running a logistic regression. Treatment is a factor with 3 levels. I am assuming that intercept is one of these 3 levels (negative control in this case). Is there a reason the equation is splitting the predictor variable like this?

````
Call:
glm(formula = propgfp ~ treatment, family = quasibinomial, data = frass4glm)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7631  -0.0001   0.6031   0.6964   0.8529  

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         -19.87    3390.23  -0.006    0.995
treatmentFrass       22.64    3390.23   0.007    0.995
treatmentPositive    22.64    3390.23   0.007    0.995

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 1.324805)

    Null deviance: 100.322  on 34  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  25.863  on 32  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA
```
````

Comment: You have a predictor with three levels. Two levels plus one (the intercept) is three. What is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable has three levels. One is subsumed by the intercept. One is the binary variable `treatmentFrass` that is $1$ when the treatment is `Frass` and zero otherwise. One is the binary `treatmentPositive` that is $1$ when the treatment is `Positive` and zero otherwise. This way, only the intercept is active when the treatment is neither `Frass` nor `Positive`; the parameter on `treatmentFrass` gives you the estimated difference in the outcome between the omitted category (that is subsumed by the intercept) and the `Frass` group; and the parameter on `treatmentPositive` gives you the estimated difference in the outcome between the omitted category (that is subsumed by the intercept) and the `Positive` group.

This is the same as why a three-factor variable in an ANOVA regression is split into two categories with the third subsued by the intercept.

Comment: @LiamTSullivan It would help if you explained what you meant by "the effect of treatment as a whole". This makes it sound like you lack a control group.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for the correction. The positive and negative are the respective controls, so I am looking for the effect of the frass treatment against these two. I think I see my issue.

Comment: For clarity. I misunderstood your explanation initially, thanks all for the help here! Statistics is a weak point for me and I am glad to have your input.